# How can I get my personal notes within the console to change color?

Tags: r

[Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EiitM.png) My ## tag is not changing color, what can I do to change that?

I have tried looking for a solution in my settings, but there has been no luck.

Answer (score 1):

The console isn't a place to make and keep notes. The console isn't something that gets saved, so if you are trying to add notes to a script, you probably want to create a new script.

In R itself, I am not sure if or how you have notes (in scripts) change colors, but this happens automatically in some "Integrated Development Environments (IDE)", such as RStudio. For learning how to use R, I would recommend downloading RStudio. When you create a script there, your comments starting with `#` will automatically be a different color than code.